# parsing JSON with jq to return value of element where another element has a certain value

Tags: json, filtering, jq

I have some JSON output I am trying to parse with jq. I read some examples on filtering but I don't really understand it and my output it more complicated than the examples. I have no idea where to even begin beyond `jq '.[]'` as I don't understand the syntax of jq beyond that and the hierarchy and terminology are challenging as well. My JSON output is below. I want to return the value for `Valid` where the `ItemName` equals `Item_2`. How can I do this?

```
"1"
[
  {
    "GroupId": "1569",
    "Title": "My_title",
    "Logo": "logo.jpg",
    "Tags": [
      "tag1",
      "tag2",
      "tag3"    
    ],
    "Owner": [
      {
        "Name": "John Doe",
        "Id": "53335"
      }
    ],
    "ItemId": "209766",
    "Item": [
      {
        "Id": 47744,
        "ItemName": "Item_1",
        "Valid": false
      },
      {
        "Id": 47872,
        "ItemName": "Item_2",
        "Valid": true
      },
      {
        "Id": 47872,
        "ItemName": "Item_3",
        "Valid": false
      }
    ]
  }
]
"Browse"
"8fj9438jgge9hdfv0jj0en34ijnd9nnf"
"v9er84n9ogjuwheofn9gerinneorheoj"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except for the initial and trailing JSON scalars, you'd simply write:

```
.[] | .Item[] | select( .ItemName == "Item_2" ) | .Valid
```

In your particular case, to ensure the top-level JSON scalars are ignored, you could prefix the above with:

```
 arrays |
```